# Pressure Sensor in an Experiment

Tags: experimental-physics, pressure, vacuum, gas, inert-gases

I am running an experiment where I have a vacuum chamber attached to a vacuum pump and a pressure sensor: I use the pump to vary the pressure in the chamber between atmospheric and 1/16-th of atmospheric pressure.

I have been considering using a different gas for the pump apart from air (probably helium or argon), so I would have a canister of helium and then attach it to the entry valve.  If a different gas is used apart from air, will the pressure sensor still register the correct pressure as the amount of gas in the chamber is varied, or does the sensor need to be calibrated for the fact that a gas of different molecular weight is being used?  I am assuming that the pressure sensor still works in the same way and gives the correct reading for the pressure, but just checking.

Comment: What kind of a pressure gauge are you using? Some would need gas-specific calibration for high accuracy.

Comment: It's this one https://shop.edwardsvacuum.com/products/d02395000/view.aspx I note that it says ''It should be noted that different gasses have different thermal properties and as such the output of APGX-H is gas dependant''.

Comment: pretty odd that there isn't a data sheet available with the conversion factors. Mass Flow Controllers, which also use thermal properties, come with that. Given you aren't going down that far, something like a Barotron head might be better, although it seems to be a bit more expensive.

Comment: I am not sure if we have any funding right now to spend on a new part, I suppose I will have to calibrateit so that I know what pressure reading with the new gas corresponds to what reading for air.  Can you advise on the easiest way to do this, I only need a few different pressures anyway,.

Comment: I would get with your local Edwards folks and get a data sheet out of them. Or call one of their application engineers.

Comment: So I got in touch with Edwards and they did provide a data sheet, but it gives the pressure corresponding to different values for the output voltage.  Do I need to know have a set-up which produces the output voltage for the sensor, as that sounds like it could be slightly involved.

Answer (score -3):

Pressure is defined as force/area and that is what the sensor measures.

Comment: that doesn’t quite seem to answer the question.  Will the force be the same for different gases?

Comment: Based on clarifying what the sensor is, which is affected by the gas, this answer is incorrect.